# Remove border around pressed icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I remove the border around my icon that appears when I press it (and stays until I press somewhere else)?

```
<b-collapse :id="'accordion-' + carpool.id">
     Example Text
</b-collapse>
<span v-b-toggle="'accordion-' + carpool.id">
<span class="when-open"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></span>
<span class="when-closed"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
</span>
```

The css to hide the icon:

```
.collapsed > .when-open,
.not-collapsed > .when-closed {
    display: none;
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az7Xa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong property. The display properly will not work. Instead of "display" you should use "outline = 0 or none ".

Comment: the display property is only used to switch the icons, not for styling. Sorry if my post ist confusing. I tried adding outline none to my i tag but nothing changes

Comment: I think you can try focus property.

Comment: I guess this wasnt caused by my icon but by my span, adding span:focus {outline: none} fixed it, thanks!